# Software Solution For Boosting Low Microphone Recording Volume (Windows 7, Blue Yeti USB)

Tags: microphone, windows

When using a Blue Yeti (USB) or the built-in microphone on my g930 headset recorded volume is at an unacceptably low level.

I have tried

```
Control Panel
-> Sound
-> Recording
-> Right Click on Device X and select Properties
-> Click on the Levels Tab
-> Increase Microphone volume to 100%
```

but the sound is still not even close to loud enough.

Is there a software option out there for boosting the microphone volume recording level? I can get decent volume levels by increasing the Gain level on the Yeti, but then it picks up too much sound and the recording quality suffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is like you said, to increase the gain on the USB microphone.  When you say it picks up too much sound and the recording quality suffers, I'm assuming what you mean is that the audio signal is beginning to clip.  You just have to find the right gain level that's just loud enough to pick up what you're doing but not loud enough to where it clips.  The only way to truly be able to turn it up as loud as you want and not have recording quality suffer is if you have a limiter installed between your microphone and your computer.  Hardware limiters can be very pricey though.

Also, a really important question: are you recording into some sort of DAW?  Like Logic Pro, Pro Tools or Cubase or something like that?  If so, then you are be able to boost the volume of your signal in those DAW's by adding effects such as compression.  Let me know.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with the recording software. Was using d3dgear which had no leveling feature. I use audicity to record the mic now and d3dgear to record the video and in game sound